# Only execute methods if session value laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a controller with alot of methods than should only be allowed to be executed if I have a certain value in my session.

This is what I do at the moment:
I made a private method that can either return the value 'yes' or 'no' Wich I call in every single one of my methods that need to be verified. And if I get the return value 'yes' i run my code.

So i'm repeating myself alot in my code. There must be a better way

Comment: What is your actual question? Could you then also share some of your code the question is about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course there is a better way. You are looking for a Middleware. First, create one:

```
php artisan make:middleware SessionMiddleware
```

Edit the file you just created:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (SESSION_KEY_IS_NOT_OK) {
        abort(403);
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Register it by editing your app/Http/Kernel.php file

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'my_session' => \App\Http\Middleware\SessionMiddleware::class,
];
```

Then, in your controller, edit the constructor:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('my_session');
}
```